# portable module in Python or Perl to edit xls and save xls as csv?

Tags: python, perl, portable-applications

I am on a network and computer where nothing can be installed. On this computer i run portable apps through a USB, however I need also to to edit xls, and save as csv. Since i cannot install anything the usual xlrd xlwt wont work, except if they can be made portable? Any suggestion how to solve it?

Comment: Why can't you just install them to the USB? Do you not have access to a compiler on the system?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you say you can't install them. Just install them to your USB drive. Most source code installations allow you to specify a prefix to which the entire install will be directed.

**Example: xlwt python package**

This is even easier than a bigger C++ library that must be compiled. Just tell the setup file to install elsewhere. I have another hard drive connected to my machine called "Media"

```
$ wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlwt/xlwt-0.7.4.tar.gz#md5=231f4ff30894fc70d142b4ed1ba71cc0
$ tar zxf xlwt-0.7.4.tar.gz 
$ cd xlwt-0.7.4
$ python setup.py install --prefix /Volumes/Media/testEnv
...
Writing /Volumes/Media/testEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt-0.7.4-py2.7.egg-info
$ python
>>> import sys; sys.path.insert(0,"/Volumes/Media/testEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
>>> import xlwt
```

If I were using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) for this process, it would be even easier. Just install and activate a virtualenv on your usb, and then install the python lib. It will be in your PYTHONPATH while the env is active.